# Como crear una galeria de imagenes en Xcode 7 Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode

Hola estoy empezando a usar Xcode 7 con Swift 2 lo que necesito básicamente es en una pantalla desplegar una galeria de imagenes en la cual deben ir más menos 20 imágenes estuve buscando como poder lograr esto y lo unico que encontre es que una imagen la dividían en 3 y hacían la transición por sectores de la imagen pero eso no me sirve mucho ya que utilizaré muchas imágenes para eso. cualquier consejo o ayuda se agradece.

Comment: UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como muy bien dice @Spidvmp esa es la mejor solución. Te dejo un tutorial de los pasos que tienes que seguir para hacer lo que quieres. (http://truelogic.org/wordpress/2015/10/04/how-to-make-an-image-grid-in-swift/)   saludos.

Comment: gracias por tu post esperaba que se pudiera hacer algo distinto pero creo que eso igual ayudara gracias

Comment: Me alegro te haya servido

Comment: Gracias segui un tutorial similar el problema que tengo es que en la galería me aparece en blanco pero si presiono uno de los espacios si puedo acceder a la otra pantalla donde sale la imagen en grande que puede estar ocurriendo?

Answer (score 0):

Si usas UICollectionView te sera lo mas simple , te dejo un ejemplo de como implementarlo

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //2
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12 //numero de imágenes
    }

    //3
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //Esto se utiliza para hacer uso de celdas personalizadas
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Viewcontroller 

        cell.imagen.image = imagen que toque 
        return cell
    }
```

}

Comment: Gracias segui un tutorial similar el problema que tengo es que en la galería me aparece en blanco pero si presiono uno de los espacios si puedo acceder a la otra pantalla donde sale la imagen en grande que puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: O bien tienes el collection view con fondo trasparente o bien tienes el background de las celdas transparentes , prueba a darle color a ambas cosas , también es posible que si tu fondo es blanco y el color de las celdas es blanco , obviamente no lo diferenciaras.

Comment: probe dandole color al uicollectionview a las celdas  y al imageview ahora lo que ocurre es que aparece el recuadro pero con el color que le di sin la imagen.

Comment: Ojo por que si tienes jerárquicamente la vista por debajo de la imagen lo que se te vera es la vista y estará tapando la imagen , asegurase que la imagen esta por encima de la vista o si tu imagen esta a hidden. De todas formas cuando te pasen cosas así usa el assistan editor y haz un preview del story board  así todos los cambios que hagas los veras reflejados y podrás ir toqueteando sin tener que debutar una y otra vez.

Comment: no me resulto eso pero seguire buscando gracias de todos modos

Comment: Pon código de lo que haces y te da el error, seria muy util para encontrarlo, seguramente es una tontería que ya no ves después de pelearte tanto con tu código